# Configure nginx for two node apps, with one on a subdomain

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, digital-ocean

**Issue**

I'm trying to set up nginx so I can have my domain, `domain.com` run by a node web app on port 3000, and the subdomain `dev.domain.com` run by a second node web app on port 3001. When I run this configuration `domain.com` is connected to the right port, but `dev.domain.com` just gives a page that says the server can't be reached.

**Edit:** 
If I go to `IP_ADDRESS:3000` I get the same content as `domain.com`, but if I go to `IP_ADDRESS:3001` I get what should be at `dev.domain.com`. Based on this it seems like the apps are running fine on the right ports, and I'm just not routing the subdomain correctly.

**Code**

I edited `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` directly so it has:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name domain domain.com www.domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.domain dev.domain.com www.dev.domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    }
}
```

Other than that file everything else is a fresh install

**My logic**

I'm very new to nginx but this seems like any requests for `domain.com` would get sent to port 3000, and requests for `dev.domain.com` would go to 3001.

Any help or critique of what I've done so far would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have DNS record for dev.domain.com?

Comment: Just added an A record from `dev.domain.com` to `IP_ADDRESS`, I'll wait a bit and see if that does it

Comment: @AlexeyTen you're a genious and I'm a fool, that fixed it, I totally forgot about that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Above setup works fine. My issue was with DNS records - I added an A record directing `dev.domain.com` to the IP address of the server I'm running the node apps on.

Comment: thank you so much  i have been in the same problem much appreciated

Comment: added the same in DNS records but did not work, i removed listen property from config, but now even for abc.domain.com it is showing the first app

Answer (score 1):

Faced same issue and solved it by creating file from root user:

```
drwxr-xr-x   6 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  4096 Sep 12 06:56 .
drwxr-xr-x   4 root          root           4096 Sep 12 06:57 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root          root             11 Sep 12 06:54 .env
-rw-rw-r--   1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner   599 Sep 12 06:56 app.js
```

If you will delete all files and directories in this folder from `gitlab-runner` with `rm -Rf` command it will delete all files except `.env`

This is just quick workaround may be will be useful.

Comment: Ops, sorry, missed a window. It was related to - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153862/remove-all-files-directories-except-for-one-file